# How to perform airthmetic operation in SQL query when airthmatic operators are stored in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id  a     b    operation    c
-------------------------------
1    2    3       +          5
2    2    3       +          6
3    3    2       /          1
4    4    7       *         28
5   54    2       -         27
6    3    0       /          0
```

When we have to perform a simple arithmetic operation we simply use

```
 select a+b from table;
```

I have to use the operation column to check the value of a operation b is equal to c or not

Comment: Looks like homework. Try to code it and show your code if you encounter problems. SO is no homeworkservice. Read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

To get you started : this looks like something a sql - select wich a longer `Select [some columns], result = case when (...) then ... end from yourtable `  for a "resultcolumn" could easily solve.

Comment: Hint: `CASE WHEN`.

Comment: Another hint: Assign column value to a variable then store script in a variable then use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE**

Comment: i need the sum in select query result for showing the exact result in view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "case" would help in your ... case

```
select a,operation,b,'=',
       CASE operation
           WHEN '+' then a+b 
           WHEN '*' then a*b 
           WHEN '-' then a-b
           WHEN '/' then if(b=0,'NAN',a/b)
           else null
       end AS c
from mytable;
```